# my computer doesn't work with wine windows emulator which emulator should I use

Tags: windows, emulation

I downloaded wine windows emulator so I could download pivot stick emulator but then error messages appeared after downloading wine. so I had to remove wine so I'm searching for a windows emulator do you have any recommended for me

Comment: What do you mean with "Pivot Stick Emulator"? Do you mean Pivot **Simulator**? PS: WINE = "Wine Is Not an Emulator", it's a compatibility layer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [PlayOnLinux](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PlayOnLinux) which makes some things on Wine easier or [CrossOver](https://www.codeweavers.com/products/). Both projects automate the process of getting Windows programs to work with Wine.